# How to prettify the output coming from the SELECT query in command prompt?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I ran the simple `select` query in the command prompt,but the output rows are not coming in a single line. See below:

```
SQL> set pagesize 2000
SQL> select * from xtern_empl_rpt ;

EMP LAST_NAME
--- --------------------------------------------------
FIRST_NAME                                         SSN
-------------------------------------------------- ---------
EMAIL_ADDR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

YEARS_OF_SERVICE
----------------
001 Hutt
Jabba                                              896743856
jabba@thecompany.com
              18

002 Simpson
Homer                                              382947382
homer@thecompany.com
              20

003 Kent
Clark                                              082736194
superman@thecompany.com
               5

004 Kid
Billy                                              928743627
billythkid@thecompany.com
               9

005 Stranger
Perfect                                            389209831
nobody@thecompany.com
              23

006 Zoidberg
Dr                                                 094510283
crustacean@thecompany.com
               1


6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Could you please help me to make each rows in a single line?

***Edit***

I tried below,but still is not prettified.

```
SQL> SET LINESIZE 4000
SQL> select * from xtern_empl_rpt ;

EMP LAST_NAME                                          FIRST_NAME
                          SSN       EMAIL_ADDR
                                                         YEARS_OF_SERVICE
--- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------
------------------------- --------- --------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------- ----------------
001 Hutt                                               Jabba
                          896743856 jabba@thecompany.com
                                                                       18
002 Simpson                                            Homer
                          382947382 homer@thecompany.com
                                                                       20
003 Kent                                               Clark
                          082736194 superman@thecompany.com
                                                                        5
004 Kid                                                Billy
                          928743627 billythkid@thecompany.com
                                                                        9
005 Stranger                                           Perfect
                          389209831 nobody@thecompany.com
                                                                       23
006 Zoidberg                                           Dr
                          094510283 crustacean@thecompany.com
                                                                        1

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

set your column widths to fit in the screen

eg:

```
column EMAIL_ADDR format a30
```

where a is hte column width. you can use WRA to wrap the column
eg

```
column EMAIL_ADDR format a30 WRA
```

or `TRU` to truncate, `WOR` to break on word boundaries

for example:

```
SQL> select * from emp;

        ID FIRST_NAME
---------- ------------------------------
LAST_NAME
------------------------------
EMAIL_ADDR
--------------------------------------------------
         1 Dazza
Smith
d_dazzal@dazzal.com
```

so the output is a bit tricky to read as email_addr was padded to 300 characters (as my table had it defined as varchar2(300) which sql*plus uses to format the output).

first set an appropriate linesize:

```
   SQL> set linesize 100
```

now lets set the columns so they fit on one line (linesize should be greater than the total col widths):

```
   SQL> column email_addr format a30 
   SQL> column last_name format a20 
   SQL> column first_name format a20 
   SQL> select * from emp;

            ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME            EMAIL_ADDR
    ---------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------
             1 Dazza                Smith                d_dazzal@dazzal.com
```

so now the columns fit easily onto a reasonably sized terminal.

in your case `first_name` and `last_name` are varchar2(50)'s yet the data in them is much smaller, so i'd start with `column first_name format a15` (same for last_name). with email, your column is varchar2(100) yet the max sized output was 25 chars, so put `column email format a25` for a starter.

if you did that, you should get output (if linesize is high enough) like:

```
SQL> select * from xtern_empl_rpt ;

EMP LAST_NAME       FIRST_NAME     SSN       EMAIL_ADDR                YEARS_OF_SERVICE
--- --------------- -------------- --------- ------------------------- ----------------
001 Hutt            Jabba          896743856 jabba@thecompany.com      18
```

finally as requested. `WRA` `TRU` and `WOR`. `WRA` is default by the way, so you dont have to use it but lets say we had:

```
SQL> select * from test;

A
--------------------------------------
THIS IS A SIMPLE WRAPPING TEST
```

but i wanted to format this as 10 characters width:

S

```
QL> col a format a10 WRA
SQL> select * from test;

A
----------
THIS IS A
SIMPLE WRA
PPING TEST
```

the `WRA` means just chop the string at 10 chars, regardless of whether we are in the middle of a word or not. if we wanted to break ONLY on word endings (where possible as a word > 10 still needs to break):

```
SQL> col a format a10 WOR
SQL> select * from test;

A
----------
THIS IS A
SIMPLE
WRAPPING
TEST
```

now the output is broken at word boundaries and not necessarily at 10 chars.

if we only wanted the first 10 chars and no line wrapping, we could use `TRU`:

```
SQL> col a format a10 TRU
SQL> select * from test;

A
----------
THIS IS A
```

Comment: Sorry,I didn't get your point! can you explain it more clearly.Probably with syntaxes with my example ?

Comment: No issue, you are trying to help me out! that's all for me. Could you please also help me to understand `WRA`,`TRU`,`WOR` ?

Comment: @VBSlover a sample of that added.

Comment: Okay this works but how to set this for *all* VARCHAR2 columns?

Answer (score 10):

This should fix your issue:

```
set wrap off
```

Answer (score 8):

Try something like:

```
SET LINESIZE 120
```

(Adjust `120` to required maximum width.)

Comment: If you send the output to a file, you should find that each output row is appearing on a single line (as originally requested). If the required linesize is greater than the maximum width of your console (for example, if your console display is 80 characters wide, but your output needs to be 120 characters wide) then the output can **never** be displayed on a single line - there isn't enough room for it to fit.

Comment: Okay, Then how to send the output to a specific files from the console? give me an idea telling what commands I need to use for that purpose?

Comment: Use `SPOOL` *filename* to send output from the console to the specified *filename*, and `SPOOL OFF` to stop outputting to *filename* - see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12043.htm for more on SPOOL, and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/toc.htm for the SQLPlus Reference guide for Oracle 10.2.

Answer (score 1):

Before execute the select query, execute the following query to get the select query's output in CSV format. Then the output will be shown in CSV format.

> set markup csv on;