# Shorten the 'type' column when using desc command

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How do I shorten the `type` and `name` column when using the `desc` command?

```
SQL> desc owner
 Name                                                              Null?`    Type
----------------------------------------------------------------- -------- --------------------------------------------
OWNER_NUM                                                         NOT NULL  CHAR(4)
LAST_NAME                                                                   CHAR(50)
FIRST_NAME                                                                  CHAR(20)
ADDRESS                                                                     CHAR(15)
CITY                                                                        CHAR(15)
STATE                                                                       CHAR(2)
ZIP                                                                         CHAR(5)
```

It's really inconvenient when I have the command window snapped to half my screen.

*Update*

Using `column Type format a15` doesn't work.
My line size is already set to 120. Column commands work on all other tables I have encountered but the table retrieved from `desc` doesn't respond to column commands in the syntax I tried above.

*Update*

`set wrap off` doesn't work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prettify the output coming from the SELECT query in command prompt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547501/how-to-prettify-the-output-coming-from-the-select-query-in-command-prompt)

Comment: @JonHeller Nope. My line size is set to 120 and column commands don't work on the result of the `desc` command. At least, not in the syntax I tried it.

Comment: Woops, sorry.  I retracted my close vote.

Comment: You could use [your own query instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29670698/266304), as a script on your SQLPATH you can run with@; or as a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your linesize to a shorter size.

For example:

```
set linesize 80
```

or

```
set linesize 60
```

This appears to be the only solution, per [the SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference section on DESCRIBE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve019.htm#SQPUG040):

> To control the width of the data displayed, use the SET LINESIZE
>   command.
>
> Columns output for the DESCRIBE command are typically allocated a
>   proportion of the linesize currently specified. Decreasing or
>   increasing the linesize with the SET LINESIZE command usually makes
>   each column proportionally smaller or larger. This may give unexpected
>   text wrapping in your display. For more information, see the SET
>   command.

Comment: I guess it could work but that doesn't change the fact that the columns in the table retrieved by `desc` are way too long. I was looking for more of a column command that works for `desc` but it may be my only option if stack overflow can't come up with an alternative.