# SQL - I need to display the item name, item price, and number sold in year 2012

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to show the item name, item price, and number sold in the year 2012. I have this:

```sql
SELECT m.item_name, m.price, COUNT(od.qty) as qty, DATE_FORMAT(om.odate, '%Y') as date
FROM menu as m, order_detail as od, order_main as om
WHERE m.id = od.orderid AND DATE_FORMAT(om.odate, '%Y') = '2012'
GROUP BY m.item_name
ORDER BY qty ASC
LIMIT 7;
```

which gives me this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g60sK.png)

and I need to get it to look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk279.png)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for `sum()` not `count()`

```
SELECT m.item_name
        , SUM(m.price) as price
        , SUM(od.qty) as qty
        , DATE_FORMAT(om.odate, '%Y') as date 
FROM menu as m
INNER JOIN order_detail od ON od.orderid = m.id 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(om.odate, '%Y') = '2012'      
GROUP BY m.item_name, DATE_FORMAT(om.odate, '%Y') 
ORDER BY od.qty ASC
LIMIT 7;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check this out, it will help in prettifying your sql table output :)
[Prettifying the select statement output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14547781/9292571)

and remove the DATE_FORMAT(om.odate, '%Y') as date from your select query if you dont want it to be displayed in the output.

I believe your query must be:

> SELECT m.item_name, m.price, COUNT(od.qty) as qty FROM menu as m,
>   order_detail as od, order_main as om WHERE m.id = od.orderid AND
>   DATE_FORMAT(om.odate, '%Y') = '2012' GROUP BY m.item_name ORDER BY qty
>   ASC LIMIT 7;

Comment: This style of joining was effectively deprecated circa 1992. Anyway, it's generally discouraged here on SO.